# Trying to use variable from another function

Tags: javascript

Coming from C#, I have some problems using a variable from another function:

```
// Define colors
albumart.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var vibrant = new Vibrant(albumart);
    var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
    for (var swatch in swatches)
        if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
            var darkvibrant = swatches.DarkVibrant;
        }
})

// Toggle styles
function mainUpdate(type) {
    if (type == "music") {
        isplaying ? albumart.src = "/var/mobile/Documents/Artwork.jpg?" + milli : albumart.src = "images/No-album-art.png";
        isplaying ? icons.style.color = darkvibrant : icons.style.color = "#202727";
    }
}
```

I am trying to use `darkvibrant` in the second function, I tried this:

```
var darkvibrant = {};

darkvibrant.color = swatches.DarkVibrant;

isplaying ? icons.style.color = darkvibrant : icons.style.color = "#202727";
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: My guess is that darkvibrant isn't in scope.

Comment: You can make *darkvibrant* global, but there are other approaches (such as closures).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the variable global. So declare the `darkvibrant` variable outside the first function to make it global and then initialize in the first function.

```
var darkvibrant; // make it global
albumart.addEventListener('load', function () {
var vibrant = new Vibrant(albumart);
var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
for (var swatch in swatches)
    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
        darkvibrant = swatches.DarkVibrant;
    }
});
```

Now can be used in the second function.

Another way is that you can assign the property on the `window` object like `window.darkvibrant` and use it with the same syntax in the second function:

```
albumart.addEventListener('load', function () {
var vibrant = new Vibrant(albumart);
var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
for (var swatch in swatches)
    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
        window.darkvibrant = swatches.DarkVibrant;
    }
});
```

Comment: https://hastebin.com/apayabuven.js I tried to use it like this but it didnt work

Comment: Your code is fine there should be any other issue due to which you are unable to access the value of the variable.